# How to get Class Name in an Inheritance Structure

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to get the Class Name of a `abstract` Child class from a Parent class object.

```
public abstract class Employee  
public abstract class Faculty extends Employee
public class Professor extends Faculty

Employee bob = new Professor();
```

How do I get `Faculty` useing one of the `.getName()`, `.getSimpleName()` or similar method from the `bob` object?

Comment: Where does the class `Teacher` come from?

Comment: lol, `Teacher != Professor`

Comment: Sorry, was thinking I had put `Teacher`

Comment: You mean `Professor` :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this bob.getClass().getSuperclass()

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `bob.getClass()`. You can also use `if bob instanceof Faculty`.